# For Loop Generates Null Value in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

writing following function to add special character to an integer for example `'19991221'`. When I run the following function, it returns `NULL` value. Tried to implement [Return value from function when iterating in a loop R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375370/return-value-from-function-when-iterating-in-a-loop-r) which still returns NULL.

data is read from *.csv

```
fileloc=read.csv('*.csv')

m<-for (row in fileloc[1]) {
 x<-(sub("(..)$", "/\\1", row))
 y<-(sub("(.....)$", "/\\1", x))

}

> m
NULL


sample data:
  V1
1   19991221
2   19910703
3   19850326
4   19890328
5   19610912

Desired Result:
  V1
1   1999/12/21
2   1991/07/03
3   1985/03/26
4   1989/03/28
5   1961/09/12
```

Comment: You are right, function `for` returns `NULL`. Which of the values of the loop do you want `m` to become? `x` or `y`? Also, are those dates?

Comment: thanks Rui, yes those are dates, if there is an easy way to convert those to dates and I do not have to use for loop, I am good with that as well,

Comment: If your dataframe is named `data`, try `gsub("-", "/", as.Date(as.character(data$V1), "%Y%m%d"))
`.

Comment: Thank, you, it worked!